# Any hook for pre-plugin-update -either bulk or single plugin update

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

Any **hook** is available on before the plugin update action ? i searched in hooks library . What is the exact hook? . Doing some stuff before updating plugin/theme .

Answer (score 1):

**Here are two untested ideas:**

### Idea #1:

If you want to hook before an instance of the `Plugin_Upgrader` class is created with:

```
$upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader( ... )
```

where the upgrades are activated with:

```
$upgrader->upgrade($plugin);          // for a single plugin upgrade
$upgrader->bulk_upgrade( $plugins );  // for bulk plugins upgrades
```

then you could try:

```
/**
 * Idea #1 - Prior to plugin (bulk or single) upgrades
 */

add_action( 'admin_action_upgrade-plugin', function() {
    add_action( 'check_admin_referer', 'wpse_referer', 10, 2 );
});

add_action( 'admin_action_bulk-update-plugins', function() {
    add_action( 'check_admin_referer', 'wpse_referer', 10, 2 );
});

function wpse_referer( $action, $result )
{
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10 );

    if( $result )
    { 
        if( 'bulk-update-plugins' === $action )
        {
            // Do stuff before we run the bulk upgrade
        } 
        elseif( 'upgrade-plugin_' === substr( $action, 0, 15 )  )
        {
            // Do stuff before we run the single plugin upgrade
        }
    }
}
```

### Idea #2:

If you want to hook deeper into the `Plugin_Upgrader` object, then you could try for example to hijack the `upgrader_pre_install` filter for the *single* upgrade case:

```
/**
 * Idea #2 - Prior to a single plugin upgrade
 */

add_action( 'admin_action_upgrade-plugin', function() {
    add_action( 'upgrader_pre_install', 'wpse_upgrader_pre_install', 99, 2 );
});

function wpse_upgrader_pre_install( $return, $plugin )
{
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $return ) ) 
    {
        // Do stuff before we run the single plugin upgrade
    }
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 99 );
    return $return;
}
```

Similarly you could hijack the `upgrader_clear_destination` filter for the *bulk* upgrades:

```
/**
 * Idea #2 - Prior to bulk plugins upgrade
 */

add_action( 'admin_action_bulk-update-plugins', function() {
    add_action( 'upgrader_clear_destination', 'wpse_upgrader_clear_destination', 99, 4 );
});

function wpse_upgrader_clear_destination( $removed, $local_destination, 
    $remote_destination, $plugin )
{
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $removed ) ) 
    {
        // Do stuff before we run the bulk plugins upgrades
    }
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 99 );
    return $removed;
}
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs, if it works ;-)